# Spoof referer for JavaScript requests?

Tags: javascript, html, http-headers

I'm running a local HTML "application" (HTML+JavaScript running in a browser via file:// protocol). Within that application I make JavaScript AJAX requests to a server. Is there a way to spoof the HTTP referer for those requests?

Currently, I have a browser extension installed which does the referer spoofing, however, this seems like overkill if the HTML is already executed by me using the file:// protocol (I guess it is forbidden for http(s)://-loaded HTML applications in order to give the user control over the referer policy). So is there a way for file://-protocol loaded pages? If no, why not?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Have you tried using a proxy?

Comment: I don't follow: I'm trying to achieve "spoof HTTP referer of JavaScript-induced HTTP request". A proxy from within JavaScript? I could use a system-wide or browser-wide HTTP proxy, yes, but I guess the browser extension is a simpler workaround...and I want to get rid of all those workarounds.

Comment: [Forbidden Header Names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name) includes "referer" as one that can not be changed programatically. Lots of search results on how to do it using a plugin or proxy.

Comment: Yeah, I've got a plugin installed now. But I can't really see why they block this. Does it make sense for file://-protocol loaded pages? I can't see why...

Comment: @D.R. See [Fetch API: referrer policy](https://dev.opera.com/blog/opera-39/#fetch-api-referrer-policy)